# Formatting date with EJS/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a string with the following format:

```
2020-05-01T23:59:59
```

And I'd like the output to be formatted like so:

```
May 1, 2020 - 11:15pm
```

But I'm finding all kinds of conflicting info and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: nothing works? what doesn't work? you haven't tried anything - step 1 - get the date as a Date object `new Date('2020-05-01T23:59:59')` - from there it's easy

Comment: How about `moment('2020-05-01T23:59:59').format("MMM D, YYYY - hh:mma")`;

Comment: @hoangdv - you'll probably need to mention that `moment` is a library, not built in to JS

Comment: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'}).formatToParts(new Date('2020-05-01T23:59:59')).reduce((r,s,i) => \`${r}${i === 5 ? ' - ' : i === 9 ? '' : i === 10 ? s.value.toLowerCase() : s.value}\`, '')`

Comment: @hoangdv - all good - was wondering - my comment deleted :p

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have two options:

The first, and probably easier of the two options is to use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), which can easily achieve this like so:

```
moment().format("MMM D, YYYY - hh:mma")
// Should produce May 1, 2020 - 11:15pm
```

Or, if you must use vanilla JS, or are reluctant to install another package, you can do the following:

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-us", {
  month: "long",
  day: "numeric",
  year: "numeric",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  hour12: true
});
const dateParts = Object.fromEntries(dateFormatter.formatToParts(currentDate).map(({ type, value }) => [type, value]));

const dateString = `${dateParts.month} ${dateParts.day}, ${dateParts.year} - ${dateParts.hour}:${dateParts.minute}${dateParts.dayPeriod.toLowerCase()}`;
// dateString should now contain the string May 1, 2020 - 11:15pm
```

Comment: If vanilla JS can do it, why install a library with all sorts of other bloat you don't need - by the way, your vanilla solution doesn't work - since dateParts is an ARRAY

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, give me a moment.

Comment: simple fix - `const dateParts = Object.fromEntries(dateFormatter.formatToParts(date).map(({ type, value }) => [type, value]));`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, fixed up the vanilla js with your fix, and fixed some other mistakes I made with it as well.

Comment: This works great and is very clean. Unfortunately, this overrides the 'literal' separator entries with the last literal value in the array, e.g literal will be '':" from the seconds entry. The literal separator from the date part is lost.

`0: {type: "day", value: "04"}`
`1: {type: "literal", value: "/"} --> will get lost`
`.......`
`9: {type: "literal", value: ":"} --> will be used as literal`
`10: {type: "second", value: "50"}`
`